# Grunt uglify fail while with JS Parse error

Tags: angularjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I've created an Angular app which works fine on locally.
However when I try to build (grunt build) to generate the dist folder that will contain my app with everything minified and ready to deploy, I have a error at the Uglify step.

Error:

```
JS_Parse_Error {
  message: 'Unexpected token operator «=», expected punc «,»',
  filename: '../../.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js',
  ...
```

I've read that people had similar errors, just the operator was a different one in the error message.
If someone has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue came from the function's parameters with a default value.

For example:

```
function (a = myValue, b) {
...
```

For some reason, giving that default value was not supported.

I replaced it by doing something like:

```
function (a, b) {
  a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : myValue;
  ...
```

You will find explanations of that behaviour by googling (uglify, ES6), I'm just offering the solution of my specific error.